# modifying log4j2.xml in a running tomcat

Tags: tomcat7, log4j2

We have a WAR deployment in a tomcat 7 container which has its `log4j2.xml` file located under the deployment's `WEB-INF/classes` folder and, the `logj42.xml` file is configured with `monitorInterval="30"`.

We want to modify the `log4j2.xml` to contain a new `<Logger>` node and we want to do this while the deployment is running (i.e. have the `monitorInterval` bit of log4j2 pick up the new `Logger` after 30secs).

When we modify the `log4j2.xml` file under `webapps/{deployent-name}/WEB-INF/classes`, no changes take place within the running deployment. We verify this by using jconsole to connect to the tomcat server and look at the `org.apache.logging.log4j2` `Loggers` jmx beans within... but we don't see any new Loggers listed.

Is it possible to actually add a new Logger to a running deployment's log4j2 configuration? And if so, is it just a case of modifying the `log4j2.xml` file of the deployment under `webapps\{deployment-name}\WEB-INF\classes`? or would we have to modify the log4j2.xml file in the tomcats' `temp\...` file? or something else entirely?

Comment: Yes, this should be working.  Please add status="DEBUG" to your <configuration> element and if it is not working attach that to a new Log4j 2 Jira issue.

Comment: The output from adding `<Configuration status="debug"` to your configuration will show the location of the configuration file that is actually loaded.

Comment: @rgoers/@Remko, I can verify that the `log4j2.xml` configuration file that is actually being monitored for changes is actually the one in the tomcat container's `temp` folder location. So it is only when I modify the log4j2.xml file in the temp folder that the changes take effect for the running deployment. Is the intended behaviour?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808700/how-to-change-logger-level-in-log4j2-xml-at-runtime-without-restarting-tomcat-se/62884212#62884212, It might help.